# Swift UIAlertAction segue data pass

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uialertaction

I am using a UIAlertAction to ask the user if they want to go to that users profile. Not sure what I am doing wrong because the data doesn't pass correctly and returns nil. Not sure If I need to have the "prepareForSegue" outside the UIAlertAction... I guess the segue passes before the data with this current setup?

```
let profileAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Go To Profile", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { action in self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "followingfeed", sender: self)

        let dataPass = self.feeds[sender.tag].dataPass

        func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
            if segue.identifier == "followingfeed" {

                    let user = dataPass
                    let controller = segue.destination as? ExploreBusinessProfileSwitchView
                    controller?.otherUser = user

            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prepareForSegue` should be a class's instance method

```
let profileAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Go To Profile", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { action in 
  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "followingfeed", sender:self.feeds[sender.tag].dataPass)
})
```

//

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
     if segue.identifier == "followingfeed" {
         let user = sender as! [String:Any]
         let controller = segue.destination as? ExploreBusinessProfileSwitchView
         controller?.otherUser = user 
     }
}
```

Comment: "otherUser" is a NSDictionary so "User" doesn't work

Comment: replace it with what you want put better be swifty **Dictinary** or **[string:Any]**

Comment: Sorry, I am used to setting what the data is in the "prepareForSegue" so I am unsure when you say "replace it with what I want"

Comment: sweet thank you so much. I learned something new and this works!

Comment: after you develop some apps create a well formatted cv , insert them and send to the companies in your country